# Am trying to compare String with BigDecimal in openjpa using Criteria builder

Tags: openjpa, criteria-api

```
list.add(build.equal(bondRoot.get(Bond_.writingCompanyCode),dtlRoot.get(ArPstdDtl_.companycd ).as(String.class)));
```

but am getting the following error:

> Caused by:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: No metadata
>   was found for type "class java.lang.String". The class is not
>   enhanced.

Could someone help me out on this ??

Answer (score 1):

Changing type from *BigDecimal* to *String* needs conversion, not a cast. Method [as](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/Expression.html#as%28java.lang.Class%29) cannot convert from type to other - it is purely for typecasting, as documented:

> Perform a typecast upon the expression, returning a new expression
>   object. This method does not cause type conversion: the runtime type
>   is not changed. Warning: may result in a runtime failure.

Criteria API does not offer conversion from *BigDecimal* to *String*. Database vendor specific functions can be used via [CriteriaBuilder.function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html#function%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20javax.persistence.criteria.Expression...%29).